# How can I kill a process with a phrase in its name?

Tags: command-line, bash, process

I need to kill a process that contains `myName` in its description. Currently I'm doing:

```bsh
ps -ax |grep myName
I see PID
kill -9 PID
```

How can I do the same with one command without entering the PID?

Comment: Do be aware that using -9 sends a SIGKILL signal, which means that no cleanup will be done by the process, normally SIGTERM is a safer signal to send, but it obviously depends on your needs.

Comment: See the first answer to the linked duplicate, `pkill` for example allows to kill processes which match a string / regular expression.

Answer (score 56):

If `myName` is the name of the process/executable which you want to kill, you can use:

```
pkill myName
```

`pkill` by default sends the `SIGTERM` signal (signal 15). If you want the `SIGKILL` or signal 9, use:

```
pkill -9 myName
```

If `myName` is not the process name, or for example, is an argument to another (long) command, `pkill` (or `pgrep`) may not work as expected. So you need to use the `-f` option.

From `man kill`:

```
-f, --full
              The pattern is normally only matched against the  process  name.
              When -f is set, the full command line is used.
NOTES
The process name used for matching is limited to the 15 characters present
   in the output of /proc/pid/stat.  Use the -f option to match  against  the
   complete command line, /proc/pid/cmdline.
```

So:

```
pkill -f myName
```

or

```
kill -9 $(pgrep -f myName)
```

Comment: *[pkill -f myName](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760446/how-can-i-kill-a-process-with-a-phrase-in-its-name)* worked for me, process have running threads..

Answer (score 12):

With a command's name use:

```
pkill -9 myscript
```

If you are looking for a string in the command line:

```
kill -9 $(ps ax | grep myName | fgrep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

I have to warn you: the above command can send a `SIGKILL` signal to more than one process.

Answer (score 5):

There are two very neat commands `pgrep` and `pkill` that allow entering search term or part of the command name , and it will either provide the PID(s) of the process or (in case of `pkill`) kill that process.

```
$ pgrep -f firefox                                                             
23699
```

Running the same command with `pkill` and `-f` flag will close all  the firefox windows.

The `-f` flag is needed specifically to search through the full command-line of a process.

Answer (score 4):

With `pkill` and sending *signal 9*, you can kill process by name:

```
sudo pkill -9 myName
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a simple `for loop` over all the PID's associated with the specific process name, like this:

```
$ for i in $( ps ax | awk '/[m]yName/ {print $1}' ); do kill ${i}; done
```

This will kill all processes that contain the word: `myName`.