# Kill process when PID is constantly changing

Tags: process

When I issue

```
ps aux | grep mtp
```

I get

```
ubuntu-+ 15934  0.1  0.0 519848  7068 ?        Sl   21:13   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-mtp --spawner :1.9 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/20
```

So the PID in this case is 15934. But every new time this is run the PID is different. Is there any other way to kill a process other than by PID?

Comment: Check out `pkill` (to read its manpage, type `man pkill`), it allows you to kill processes by their filename and other attributes.

Comment: `killall` is also worth a try... eg. `killall mtp`.

Comment: See [How to kill the process using the name of the program instead of PID?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396684/how-to-kill-the-process-using-the-name-of-the-program-instead-of-pid) For deciding between `killall` and `kill`, [What's the difference between 'killall' and 'pkill'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27501/whats-the-difference-between-killall-and-pkill) may be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ps` to find the PID of the process, then pass that to `kill`:

```
kill $(ps -C /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-mtp -o pid=)
```

The `-C` flag specifies a command name to search for in the list of processes, and the `-o pid=` option means `ps` will print only the PID. The result is passed as the only argument to `kill`.

Answer (score 0):

I issued

```
ps aux | grep mtp
```

which gave me a few mtp related processes and compared with the camera mounted and unmounted to get the specific process

and then

```
pkill -9 gvfsd-mtp
```

does the trick. But the supplied answer above I assume will also work!